# An old Diophantine equation related to perfect binary code

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The Diophantine equation below comes from research in [perfect binary codes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectCode.html):

$$\sum_{i=0}^e{n\choose i}=2^k.$$

Here we restrict ourselves to the case where $n$, $e$, $k$ are positive integers, $e>3$.

**Question**: I calculated all cases where $3<e<21$, $n\leq10^3$, and all the possible solutions seem to be $n=1,2,\cdots e,2e+1$.

My question is: is there a proof for this statement, or is there any counterexample for it? I have no idea how to prove whether there are any other solutions or not.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I assume you have shown that those are indeed solutions.

Comment: They are indeed solutions, which can be deduced from binomial theorem without any difficulty.